# nginx - can't figure out location for / only

Tags: redirect, nginx, location, expression

I struggled a lot how to do some redirects and stuff ONLY when I enter www.example.com OR www.example.com/ but I couldn't. 
location / {} takes all cases so I tried:

```
location ~ ^/?$ {}
```

or

```
location ~ ^/$ {}
```

and many others but none worked for www.example.com or www.example.com/.

Please help... I need to match that exact location which is only when you enter www.example.com or www.example.com/.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
location = / {}
```

Comment: wow... this is really funny... I didn't tried that. I don't know, sometimes I think too much :)). I works perfectly! Thank you!